# Failing during "Creating service project" when running sudo microstack.init --auto

Tags: openstack

Hello I am trying to get openstack running on a 18.4 ubuntu box I am hitting the following error.

```
2020-03-04 09:12:52,823 - microstack_init - INFO - Creating service project ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/microstack/196/bin/microstack_init", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('microstack-init==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'microstack_init')()
  File "/snap/microstack/196/lib/python3.6/site-packages/init/main.py", line 122, in main
    question.ask()
  File "/snap/microstack/196/lib/python3.6/site-packages/init/questions/question.py", line 210, in ask
    self.yes(awr)
  File "/snap/microstack/196/lib/python3.6/site-packages/init/questions/__init__.py", line 373, in yes
    'service')
  File "/snap/microstack/196/lib/python3.6/site-packages/init/shell.py", line 68, in check
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, " ".join(args))
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'openstack project create --domain default --description Service Project service' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 3):

I hated trying to find a solution to this problem. I got the error also. Would you believe all it took was 1 piece of code.

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.microstack.*
```

Should do it. Hope this helps. I'm guessing you turned off your pc after you did the initial Init. Basically the service stops after you do this and you need to restart it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It took me 4h to see your answer ;)